# ubercart role expiration

Tags: ubercart

I hope this question is neither a clone nor a stupid one, but I need to fix/understand this very quickly, I did some research though.

Coming to my problem:
I am building a no-profit website and we do require a small fee for the participants.
So I am using Ubercart to allow people to buy the "Participant" role.

I set everything up and also the payment system works properly.
My problem is the expiration. In the product I set the expiration to 1 year, but when a user registers no expiration is set. 
When I go to **People -> Role expiration**, the table is empty saying "No expirations set to occur".

I followed some tutorials on-line and I believe I did everything right, can you guys help me with this?

I also think I properly set the permission, even though I have some doubts about.

Thank you,
guidout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
The Role expiration entry is not created when a NEW user registers to the website buying the role. 
If an existing user buys the role, it shows up properly in Role Expiration.

If anybody knows how to go around this problem it would be great.
Thanks for the help Aparna

Answer (score 2):

```
Edit your product. 
Go to features. 
From the Add a new feature, Add both recurring fee and role assignment for your product.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work...still showing nothing in the Role expiration

Comment: Once your payment is completed,what is the status that is shown for the order that you made? @ http://example.com/admin/store/orders/view

Comment: surprisingly I just realized that the status is "Pending". I dont know why...the payment goes well and is completed...now the role assignment is not working neither. I assume that it is because of the pending status. Even after changing the status to "Complete", the user does not get the role...

Comment: Change the status to Payment Received. And then see

Comment: I already changed the status to "Complete", therefore I cant change to "Payment Received" anymore. I will do try it next time somebody buys something. Thanks for the help, but the Role expiration still remains mysterious...

Comment: I guess when the role assignment is made after changing the status to "Payment Received" then the role expiration will also work.

Comment: Yes, just verified that when I change the status to "Payment Received", the user gets the correct Role. Thanks for the hint. BUT still nothing for the "Role expiration"...this really looks odd to me...